# JPA Metamodel Generator doesn't create all fields

Tags: java, jpa

This is my class:

```
@Embeddable
public class QuarterIntValues {
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private int valueRR;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private int valueRL;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private int valueFL;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private int valueFR;
}
```

And this is the generated Metamodel:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
    @StaticMetamodel(QuarterIntValues.class)
    public abstract class QuarterIntValues_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<QuarterIntValues, Integer> value;
```

}

I expected that the metamodel processor generates a field for every field that I created in the original class. Am I missing or misunderstanding something? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Strange... now it works. I removed the MetamodelProcessor from Eclipse and added it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. You need to create getter and setter for the fields in your class. The metamodelProcessor generates the fields in the metamodel class then.

Comment: Correction: You only need getters.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent several hours trying to figure out why a json field was not showing up in the generated metamodel for Hibernate6. In my case, the missing piece was the @Embeddable and @Embedded tags.

for example

the json

```
@Embeddable
public class MrJson {

  @JsonProperty("mr_json_field")
  String mrJsonField;

  // more fields 

  // getters+setters

}
```

and the entity class

```
@Entity
public class MrsEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Embedded
  @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
  private MrJson mrJson;

  // more fields 

  // getters+setters

}
```

sauce: https://thorben-janssen.com/things-to-know-when-migrating-to-hibernate-6-x/#6_Mapping_JSON_documents_got_easier

hope that saves you some pain fellow sleepy engineer ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but my issue was due to missing a generated Id in the entity class as in below:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
Integer xxx;
```

That fixed my issue.

As a new comer to JPA, seems like every entity table needs it?